# Can you change teams?

Tags: pokemon-go

Can you change your team over once you've chosen a team or is it permanent?

Comment: You can also request to change your team in its official website.

Comment: @DeMize If this is true, you should make it an answer.

Comment: No, but the future is a different story. On the support site, it states "Unfortunately, we are unable to change make team changes at this time". This means that there maybe a future update where you can change your team.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of [February 26, 2019](https://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/teamchange2019/), the feature to switch teams has been implemented. You can switch teams by purchasing the new "Team Medallion" item from the shop.

While the ability to switch teams is now available, there are a few things that need to be considered:

- > Interested Trainers will be able to purchase a Team Medallion for 1,000 PokéCoins from the shop.
- > Choose your team wisely, Trainers, as you may only purchase a Team Medallion once every 365 days.
- > Any of your Pokémon that are in Gyms when you change teams will be returned with no PokéCoins earned once it’s defeated. You also can’t battle your own Pokémon, so if you return to a Gym one of your Pokémon is defending, your Pokémon will be returned to you with no PokéCoins earned

Answer (score 26):

As it stands, no. The team you select is permanent, however, you can make a new account and request your old one to be deleted (available on their website) if you'd like to switch teams, at the cost of all your progress.

Comment: Rumors are, though, that there will be an update where this changes. You will be able to access a box then, just like in the main games. There is nothing confirmed yet, but some page I don't remember showed some leaks.

Comment: Actually, this refers to the Pokemon team that will apparently be added. I also remember stumbling upon that the page said the update would "feature a Pokemon Team concept" and wondering why this should be new. Now that I informed myself more deeply, the information makes sense.

Comment: Do you have a specific link of where one would go to request this? I can't find it.

Comment: @Unionhawk digital trend has an article on how to do this here: http://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/deleting-pokemon-go-account-isnt-easy/